# Trick client into connecting to unsecure evil twin Wi-Fi access point

Tags: wifi

Let's say I create an **unsecured** evil twin for a Wi-Fi AP that is **secured**.

If I successfully deauth the victim and get his device to choose my evil twin to connect to, will he get a message alerting him that this network was previously secured and that now it's not?
Or will the device try to reconnect without providing a password?

If it's a case of "it depends", what does it depend on? The device's OS Wi-Fi implementation? Or the Wi-Fi protocol used?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot make a client to connect to you if the original ssid is secured and evil twin one is insecure .

Comment: .after deauth it will connect back to original one only

Comment: @BadSkillz not a duplicate, I'm not talking about capturing the password.

Answer (score 0):

The user's device can distinguish the Evil Twin from the original AP

In this case the attack can't work if the deauthenticated user doesn't connect manually to your evil twin (And he doesn't notice it's not protected)